# TFS 2015 disabling 'CODE', 'BUILD', 'TEST', 'RELEASE'

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

Is there a way to disable the menu options 'CODE', 'BUILD', 'TEST', 'RELEASE' in TFS 2015?
Reason I ask is because they are not used.

Comment: Which menu options will you have left? Those listed are the majority of the useful options on the TFS web interface.

Comment: TFS is merely used as a Kanban board, nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable 'CODE', 'BUILD', 'TEST' by [changing access levels](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/connect/change-access-levels), you can assign **Stakeholder** access to those users who need to enter bugs, view backlogs, boards, charts, and dashboards, but who don't have a TFS CAL. But Stakeholders can also view releases and manage release approvals, so you can't disable 'RELEASE' tab.

[image]

Comment: TFS is merely used as a Kanban board by the project team.

Comment: @Rick Does changing access levels help you?

Comment: Unfortunately, changing access level to Stakeholder does not restrict the user from seeing the other menu options.  Besides, the users will need the basic access level to conduct their work.  Stakeholder is fine for read only purposes.